# What is the etymology of “yellow”, and why is it so different in other European languages?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, history, colors

It seems like most of our names for colors come from our German roots (*blue/blau, green/grün, red/rot*, etc.). But *yellow* is *gelb* in German, *amarillo* in Spanish, *jaune* in French, and *giallo* in Italian. I suppose the Italian seems closest, but perhaps they all have something in common?

Comment: Spanish *amarillo* is from Latin *amarĕllus* derived from [*amārus* meaning “bitter”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amarus#Latin). Wiktionary hyphesizes that this may be because of the yellowish color of bile, which is bitter, but we don’t know for sure.

Comment: @tchrist As I noted in my answer, *gall* has the same "yellow" root/etymology, so that connection makes sense. The spanish suffix *-illo* is a diminutive, so *amarillo* literally means "a bit bitter".

Comment: Fun fact: *orange* used to be called *geoluread* (*yellowred*).

Comment: Also: gall bladder, jaundice.

Comment: @ghoppe That isn’t quite right. The Spanish word for bitter is *amargo*. It has with an extra *g* compared with the Latin *amarus*. So you would be thinking of something more like *amarguillo*. The reason there is no *g* there is because it didn’t happen that way, but rather came down to us from Latin *amarellus* without ever hitting *amargo* to get here.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The word for the colour *yellow* [comes from a germanic root as well](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=yellow).

> Old English geolu, geolwe, from Proto-Germanic *gelwaz (cf. Old Saxon, Old High German gelo, Middle Dutch ghele, Dutch geel, Middle High German gel, German gelb, Old Norse gulr, Swedish gul "yellow"), from PIE *ghel- "yellow, green" (see Chloe).

Palatalization is a sound change that took place from Old English to Modern English. Here's a short list of words where this shift took place: *day* (German *Tag*), *yarn* (German *Garn*), *way* (German *Weg*), *year* (Old English *gear*), *nail* (German Nagel), *yield* (Old English *geldan*, Old High German *geltan*) and *thirsty* (German *durstig*). It also happened with another colour word: *gray* (Old English *græg*.)

It should be noted that in Modern German, the terminal *g* has become devoiced and *Tag* sounds more like *tuck* in English.

The word is similar in Latin languages because they all share the same Proto-Indo-European root, **ghel-*. It's interesting that this same root which had the meaning "to shine" gave us not only the colour yellow, but also *gold, gild, gall* (i.e. yellow-coloured bile), and a range of sparkly *gl-* words: *glitter, gleam, glow*, etc.

Comment: Now THAT is an informative answer!

Comment: +1 and gestern => yesterday which is close to gelb => yellow.

Comment: The [AHD of PIE (2000) entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20080720062900/http://bartleby.com/61/roots/IE158.html) for _*ghel-²_.

Comment: What kind of German should include "geltan". Never heard this.

Comment: The forms ["geluw" and "gelluw" for "yellow" are historically attested in Dutch](http://gtb.inl.nl/iWDB/search?actie=article_content&wdb=WNT&id=M018866) but no longer in use; clearly German "gelb" and modern Dutch "geel" have developed from it.

Comment: @reinierpost I took the germanic word from etymonline.com, I clarified in my post. I think the modern German word is *gelten* but the original meaning of "to pay" has gone down different paths in both German and English.

Comment: Slightly inaccuracy: palatalisation happened before the stage of Old English. It is common to Anglo-Frisian (quoting from a possibly leaky memory, Old Frisian has for example such forms as _dei_ ‘day’ and something like _ief_ ‘gives’). Also, I’d say German _Tag_ today sounds more like BrE ‘tark’ or AmE ‘tock’, rather than ‘tuck’ (in either).

Comment: Also (11 months later), _grey_ is an interesting word, because there actually **isn't** any palatalisation in it. The OED spelling with a final _g_ is purely orthographic, based on words like _dæg_, which proves that the palatalisation had already been completed by that time, and that written _g_ in front-vowel environments simply represented /j/.

Answer (score 10):

It’s from the Germanic root *gel* which has produced both English *yellow* and German *gelb* (OED).

Comment: Not *gel* but *gelw*.

Comment: It depends how far back you want to go. The hypothetical Old Germanic root was _gelwa_ and the hypothetical Indo-European was _ghelwo_.

Comment: The point is that the *-ow* and *-b* weren't added onto the preexisting word.

Comment: @reinierpost, perhaps not in Germanic as such, but going farther back, the root is indeed just _*gʰel-_. The w is part of the suffix, not part of the root; it is absent in other derivatives (see cognates in ghoppe’s answer).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: yes, but you don't need to go further back, and Barrie writes 'Germanic'.

Comment: @reinier, obviously it's hard to tell where the distinguishing line between a root and a word lies in a reconstructed language; but I don't think it's that far-fetched to say that the root was thought of as _*gel-_ in Germanic times, and that _*-wa_ was still recognisably a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I thought to supplement the other excellent answers with more information about the PIE root *ghel-.

[This website](http://morphemeaddict.com/article/gl-words-and-ghel) lists more derivatives, but references p 29, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots* by Calvert Watkins, on which the entry **ghel-**<sup>2</sup> lists many more derivatives an so is too long to reproduce here; so I quote only the underlying semantic field:

> to shine ine with derivatives referring to colors, 
>   bnght materials. gold (probably "yellow metal"). and 
>   bile or gall. (Oldest form *g `[There is a diacritic atop g, but I cannot see which diacritic it is from Google Books.]` hel-.)

Comment: Perhaps it is a “ġ”, U+0121 LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH DOT ABOVE?